# Not able to deploy to Kubernetes cluster using Kompose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubectl, kompose

I'm currently deploying a project on a kubernetes cluster by using Kompose (http://www.kompose.io) to convert the docker-compose configuration to kubernetes configuration files.

This is a project for a master class at my university and they took care of the kubernetes cluster, so I'm almost certain that the configuration for it is done properly. FYI, this is the version of that kubernetes cluster;

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:23:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:13:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

This is the version of Kompose;

```
$ kompose version
1.20.0 (f3d54d784)
```

The problem that I have is as follows. I use the command kompose convert and this works without any problem, but when I try deploying it by using the command kompose up, it fails with the following error message.

```
FATA Error while deploying application: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
```

This is my first time using kubernetes and kompose. I've looked for others who also have this problem but nothing really helped for what I've found.

This is my docker-compose file at the moment:
(I'm aware I shouldn't put passwords in my docker-compose file but it's not part of the problem)

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper-container:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
  kafka-container:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper-container
    environment: 
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper-container:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka-container:9092
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1

  route-db:
    image: neo4j:3.5.6
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/route
    ports:
      - 7687:7687
  delay-request-db:
    image: redis

  staff-db:
    image: mongo
  train-db:
    image: mongo

  maintenance-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=maintenancedatabase
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=Maintenance
  station-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=stationdatabase
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=Station
  ticket-sale-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ticketsaledatabase
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=TicketSale
  ticket-validation-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ticketvalidationdatabase
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=TicketValidation
  timetable-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=timetabledatabase
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=Timetable

  delay-service:
    build: ./railway-app-delay
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-delay-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-delay/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
  maintenance-service:
    build: ./railway-app-maintenance
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-maintenance-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-maintenance/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - maintenance-db
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - maintenance-db
  route-service:
    build: ./railway-app-route-management
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-route-management-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-route-management/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - route-db
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - route-db
  staff-service:
    build: ./railway-app-staff
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-staff-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-staff/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - staff-db
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - staff-db
  station-service:
    build: ./railway-app-station
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-station-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-station/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - station-db
      - delay-request-db
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - station-db
      - delay-request-db
  ticket-sale-service:
    build: ./railway-app-ticket-sale
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-ticket-sale-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-ticket-sale/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - ticket-sale-db
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - ticket-sale-db
  ticket-validation-service:
    build: ./railway-app-ticket-validation
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-ticket-validation-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-ticket-validation/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - ticket-validation-db
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - ticket-validation-db
  timetable-service:
    build: ./railway-app-timetable
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-timetable-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-timetable/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - timetable-db
      - route-service
      - station-service
      - train-service
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - timetable-db
      - route-service
      - station-service
      - train-service
  train-service:
    build: ./railway-app-train
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-train-service
    volumes: 
      - ./railway-app-train/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - train-db
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - train-db
  apigateway:
    build: ./railway-app-api-gateway
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-api-gateway-service
    volumes:
      - ./railway-app-api-gateway/target:/app
    links:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - delay-service
      - maintenance-service
      - route-service
      - staff-service
      - station-service
      - ticket-sale-service
      - ticket-validation-service
      - timetable-service
      - train-service
    depends_on:
      - kafka-container
      - zookeeper-container
      - delay-service
      - maintenance-service
      - route-service
      - staff-service
      - station-service
      - ticket-sale-service
      - ticket-validation-service
      - timetable-service
      - train-service
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  frontend:
    build: ./railway-app-frontend
    image: gilliswerrebrouck/railway-app-frontend
    volumes:
      - ./railway-app-frontend/target:/app
    links:
      - apigateway
      - route-db
    depends_on:
      - apigateway
      - route-db
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Anyone has any tips on how to troubleshoot this issue or how to fix it?

UPDATE:

These are the files generated by the `kompose convert` command

[image]

Comment: It sounds like a liveness or readiness probe is failing to connect to your railway-app-api-gateway container; you'll need to post the actual manifests that `kompose` is deploying if you insist on using it. Perhaps increasing its vebosity might output them, or if it actually _did_ deploy them, then `kubectl get --all-namespaces -o yaml deploy` should show you what is currently deployed

Comment: It isn't deployed, this is an error I get while deploying it. I've executed that command you mention to be sure but nothing is deployed. The 8080 port is the same (by accident) for my api-gateway service as for something that kubernetes exposes. The error about not being able to call localhost:8080 is a kubernetes error itself.

Comment: @mdaniel: I've also added a screenshot of all the files generated by the kompose convert command, there are so many files, I can't post them all to this question. I also don't think it's an issue with those files but rather with how Kompose tries to connect to the local kubernetes cluster to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it by replacing all apiversions in the deployment files from v1beta2 to apps/v1 and by adding a selector to each deployment.

```
selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ...
```

I then didn't use the command `Kompose up` to deploy since this gives me an error, but I used the command `kubectl create -f <file(s)>` to deploy and this succeeded without the connection error. There are still some pods crashing but I don't think it has anything to do with this original problem.