# Why does kompose up yields "connection refused"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, kompose

Running `docker-compose up` on a simple web app works as expected. Running `kompose up` on the same app while attempting to connect to a Google Cloud cluster doesn't work:

```
...
INFO We are going to create Kubernetes Deployments, Services and PersistentVolumeClaims for your Dockerized application. If you need different kind of resources, use the 'kompose convert' and 'kubectl create -f' commands instead. 

FATA Error while deploying application: Get http://127.0.0.1:6443/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connect: connection refused
```

What are possible causes of this problem?

[Other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60637718/3272066) here on SO do not help, and I can't find any other relevant result on the web.

Comment: what are you trying to reach on the localhost exactly?

Comment: Actually I'm quite new to Kubernetes, and I guess I would just like to reach my newly created cluster on Google Cloud. What is this `127.0.0.1:6443/api` endpoint?

Comment: Probably that's the default endpoint. You want to reach a GKE cluster, or you built one?

Comment: I built a GKE cluster (following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart).

Comment: then your endpoint is the master's external IP. If you click on the cluster, you should see the IP address, from the console. But I don't know how to configure kompose. have never used it.

Comment: Thank you. Are you then suggesting that my Kubernetes is not pointing to my cluster? If so, it would already be useful if you could suggest how to troubleshoot this directly with `kubectl`. (I am just using Kompose because it's supposed to be easier, but I'm also glad to fix my issue with `kubectl` directly.)

Comment: `kubectl` is the kubernetes client. First, you need to deploy all your stuff on kubernetes. Yes, my guess is that your kompose is converting the files and is trying to deploy to kubernetes; thinking that the `api-server` is running on the same machine, which is not the case, because you are on GKE.

Comment: I am not sure whether the difference in the apiversions is causing this issue. I found [this similar discussion thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690266/not-able-to-deploy-to-kubernetes-cluster-using-kompose), where the issue is resolved by replacing the apiversions.

Comment: Thank you @Digil. I just checked, and apparently Kompose already took care of putting `v1` or `apps/v1` in the generated files. But I'll post an update if I find something else.